cuobjdump emit no PTX arithmetic instruction
Why doesn't cuobjdump emit the PTX mul instruction below? Has nvcc optimized the cubin output iteself? Is the result calculated at compile-time? If so, for this simplest case nvcc can reasonably further optimize the output w/o generating any instructions on the device side at all.
mul.cu
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void mul(float *res) {
    float x = 11.1, y = 22.2;
    *res = x * y;
}

int main() {
    float *res;
    cudaMallocManaged(&res, sizeof(float));
    mul<<<1, 1>>>(res);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("11.1 * 22.2 = %f\n", *res);
}

Problem
$ nvcc mul.cu -o mul

$ ./mul

11.1 * 22.2 = 246.420013

$ cuobjdump -fun mul -ptx ./mul

...

.visible .entry _Z3mulPf(
.param .u64 _Z3mulPf_param_0
)
{
.reg .b32 %r<2>;
.reg .b64 %rd<3>;


ld.param.u64 %rd1, [_Z3mulPf_param_0];
cvta.to.global.u64 %rd2, %rd1;
mov.u32 %r1, 1131834246;
st.global.u32 [%rd2], %r1;
ret;

}



Is the result calculated at compile-time?

Yes.
The compiler can observe that the result will always be 11.1x22.2, so it simply puts that value (when the float bit pattern is viewed as a decimal integer: 1131834246) into the result location.
If you want to see the mul instruction, make the multiplication input values be kernel arguments:
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void mul(float *res, float x, float y) {
    *res = x * y;
}

int main() {
    float *res;
    cudaMallocManaged(&res, sizeof(float));
    mul<<<1, 1>>>(res, 11.1, 22.2);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("11.1 * 22.2 = %f\n", *res);
}


If so, for this simplest case nvcc can reasonably further optimize the output w/o generating any instructions on the device side at all.

Any proper optimization still has to have the same result in global state.  So in this case, it would probably be acceptable to replace the kernel with a cudaMemcpy type operation (or, since it is managed memory, perhaps simply a memcpy or some other memory setting operation), but I don't think the compiler ever tries to do that sort of optimization.

Does nvcc pre-calculate it through the host or the device? When I convert it to C and compile it in gcc,  I run it and get the result exactly same as 246.420013.  (BTW, if I use Python, it outputs the result as 246.42 more closely to that by hand ☺.) If we need compile a CUDA program on one host but deploy it on another (the compile-time host can have no GPU or different one from the deployed), could this compile-time optimization introduce any risk on portability?

Python floating point is double precision so your comparison id invalid

When I change the calculation to double precision, I get the same consistent results cross CUDA, C and Python. So it seems all FPU implementations conform to the standards and maintain cross-architecture portability.
